# Error : "Table name already exists" in Oracle Apex when trying to load the excel data in the table for first time in empty table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I created a new table in Oracle Apex

```
CREATE TABLE RFMData 
(
    InvoiceNo VARCHAR2(10),
    StockCode VARCHAR2(15),
    Description VARCHAR2(60),
    Quantity NUMBER,
    InvoiceDate TIMESTAMP,
    UnitPrice NUMBER(4,2),
    CustomerID VARCHAR(7),
    Country VARCHAR(25)
);
```

I'm trying to load the Excel file data through Load data utility feature in Apex and once I select the table and click load data, I get an error

> Table name already exists.

Steps i followed:

1. Created table using SQL command line in Apex.
2. Go on utility, Load Data/Workshop
3. Click Load Data
4. Attached the excel file in browser
5. Table name : RFMData (as created in SQL Command in step1)
6. Click on Load Data

And then after a few minutes, i get error : Table Name already exists.

Can anyone help please?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0yEp.png)

Comment: I'd say that you should provide some more info. Which Apex version do you use? How exactly did you do what you're doing (step-by-step). Because, I've just tried it (on apex.oracle.com) and no problems whatsoever. Please, do NOT add that info as a comment, but by editing the original question you posted.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for replying. I have edited the question with my steps i did as you advised.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you didn't post exactly what I asked (step-by-step) so this will still be kind of *educated guessing*.

Loading wizard asks

> Where do you want to load this data?

and offers

- new table

  - that's what you chose, I presume, because Apex tried to create a table that already exists
- existing table

  - that's what you should have chosen, because - as you said - you already created the target table

If that's so, pick the **existing table**.